# Select record from one table and add into table 2, update last inserted ID into table1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different tables `tbl_address` and `tbl_support`. I want to select `address`, `postcod`e from `tbl_support`, and `insert` into into `tbl_address` and want to `update` `address_id` in `tbl_support` with last inserted `id`. How do I write query.

```
tbl_address = id, address, postcode, country.
tbl_support = id, address_id ,name, address,postcode,
```

Answer (score 0):

if your column id field in address table autoincrement try this:

```
   insert into tbl_address select address, postcode from tbl_support;
```

then you can update tbl_support if address and postcode are unique set.

```
 update tbl_support s set s.address_id=(select id from tbl_address a where 
 a.address=s.address and a.postcode = s.postcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute to two separate queries. first you insert all tbl_support record in tbl_address table.then you need to execute second query where you update address_id through a matching tbl_address address,postcode and tbl_support address, zip code.like below query.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_address ( 
      address, 
      postcode) 
SELECT address, 
       postcode 
FROM `tbl_support`;

UPDATE `tbl_support` SET address_id = (SELECT id FROM `tbl_address` 
WHERE  tbl_support.address= tbl_address.address 
AND tbl_support.postcode= tbl_address.postcode)
```